# Subgroup of the quotient group of the commutator G'.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let G be a group and let G' be its commutator. Prove there is a one-to-one correspondence between the set of normal subgroups of G whose quotient is abelian and the set of all subgroup of G/G'.

I tried to use the fact that the commutator is a subgroup of any normal subgroup whose quotient is abelian but I can't seem to realize what correspondence I should be looking at. I would appreciate your help.

The allegedly duplicated question does not talk about the correspondence aforementioned nor does it help me in any way getting what I need to do understood.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. For every normal subgroup $H$ of G whose quotient is abelian define $f:H\to H/G'$.

Comment: gz for answering a duplicate

Comment: I still can't seem to realize how it shows that the I can pair any normal subgroups whose quotient is abelian with a subgroup of G/G' so as to show correspondence, not isomorphism...

Comment: @Meitar, my fault, I forgot to say that you can look at $H/G'$ like a subgroup of $G/G'$.

Comment: How can the above be an isomorphism? If G'<H then |H|=a, but |H/G'|=[H:G']. Let H be G', then |H|=a but |H/G'| is 1, isn't that so?

Comment: Yes, it is true. In fact $f(G')$ is a one-element subgroup.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $N \unlhd G$ then $G/N$ is abelian iff $G' \subseteq N$.

Comment: Yes I know that and took it into consideration as I said.

Comment: OK Meitar, but each subgroup of $G/G'$ can be represented as $H/G'$, where $G' \subseteq H \leq G$.